# Linux, find, regex. Поиск файла с кириллическим символом в имени

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения

Как найти все файлы рекурсивно от указанной директории с хотя бы одним любым кириллическим символом в имени. Команда

```
find ../folder/ -regex '[A-я]+'
```

ничего не находит. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Как минимум, Ваша команда говорит - найди файлы, имя которого состоит только из символов А-я (там скорее всего будут левые символы, диапазон написан неверно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. согласно документации:

   > -regex pattern
   >   This is a match on the whole path, not a search.

   т.е., шаблон должен совпадать со всем путём (и именем) файла, а не только с искомой частью (как, например, при использовании программы *grep*):

   ```
   .*[набор].*
   ```
2. сам набор букв от `А` до `Я` и от `а` до `я` должен выглядеть иначе:

   ```
   [А-Яа-я]
   ```

### итого:

```
$ find путь -regex '.*[А-Яа-я].*'
```

Comment: А как же `Ё`?..

Comment: @Qwertiy, с более или менее современной *glibc* — отлично: `find . -regex '.*[А-Яа-я].*'`, результат: `./abcdЁ123  ./abcdё123`.

Comment: спасибо, заработало. да, путь, разумеетсся, должен быть полный

Answer (score 2):

Команда должна выглядеть как минимум так

```
find ../folder/ -regex '.*[A-Яа-я].*'
```

Comment: `А-я` - мимо, и где `Ё`?

Comment: по поводу А-я - оперчатка, а Ё... тут дело вкуса. Я до сих пор не понимаю, почему ее не включили в список правильно.

Comment: @KoVadim, что значит «не включили в список»?

Comment: В прямом смысле слова. Но я тут посмотрел на таблицу юникода и скажу, что А-я вполне валидный и правильный диапазон (но только для utf-8) http://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/cyrillic/

Comment: @KoVadim *В прямом смысле слова* — это ответ на мой вопрос? тогда уточните, пожалуйста, о каком «списке, в который не включена буква ё(Ё)» идёт речь. *А-я вполне валидный и правильный диапазон* — «допустимый» диапазон (для `LC_COLLATE` со значением `язык_страна.UTF-8`): `а-Я`. аналогично и для `a-Z` (а вот для `LC_COLLATE` со значением, например, `C` — `A-z`). // смотрите про collation order в соответствующей документации.

Comment: Буква Ё не включена в список А-Я. Более того, не существует такого диапазона символ-символ, что бы он включал **все** прописные (строчные) буквы.

Comment: продолжение: например, [здесь](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html) и [здесь](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)

Comment: *Буква Ё не включена в список А-Я* — уточните, пожалуйста, о каком «списке» речь. *Более того, не существует такого диапазона символ-символ, что бы он включал все прописные (строчные) буквы* — здесь вы, вероятно, правы с теоретической т.з., но практика говорит об обратном.

Comment: например: `echo -e '1\nё\nЁ' | grep '[а-Я]'` на более или менее актуальной версии *glibc* вернёт две строки, и с буквой `ё`, и с буквой `Ё`. при переменной окружения `LC_COLLATE` со значением `язык_страна.UTF-8`.

Comment: а теперь получается такая ситуация. С одной стороны тут Qwerie пишет о букве Ё, с другой стороны она включается в список.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42330/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-kovadim).